# NameError: name 'urlstring' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting an error when I try to run this simple python script:

```
    for url in urllist:
            try:
                file = urllib2.urlopen (url)
                urlstring = file.read ()
            except:
                print "Can't open URL"
                pass
            m = [ ]
            m = re.findall (


r'file:///\\results.cal.ci.spirentcom.com\\smt\\SCMSmartTest\\\d+.\d+\\BLL\d+_IL\d+\\.*?\\TC\S+tcl',
            urlstring)
        copyFileCounts = 1
```

**Below error is displaying :**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\Python\untitled\regression.py", line 75, in 
>       urlstring) NameError: name 'urlstring' is not defined

Comment: error is obviously telling you there is now `urlstring`  so maybe your code has failed and instead of the `try`, your `except` has ran? why not move the m=re.findall() to the `try/except` thing?

Comment: Do NOT catch all exceptions! This is not Pokemon!

Comment: @JagannathaMv might want to look at the difference between `pass` and `continue`... It seems you want to go back to the top of the loop and try the next url where you couldn't open it... so that's by using `continue`...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a typo or not, but you've a space when you assign value to `urlstring` and `file`.

When using `try .. catch`, you should keep the code in the `try` block as small as possible: if something breaks, you'll know why, without much debugging.

What you can do is using an `else` clause.

> The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

So your code should look like this:

```
for url in urllist:
    try:
        file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        urlstring = file.read()
    except IOError as e:
        print "Can't open URL: {}".format(e.message)
    else:
        m = []
        m = re.findall (..)
```

You should also be more specific when catching exceptions, catching all of them is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

using the other answer to fix your code:

```
m = []
for url in urllist:
        try:
            file = urllib2.urlopen (url)
            urlstring = file.read ()
            m = re.findall (r'file:///\\results.cal.ci.spirentcom.com\\smt\\SCMSmartTest\\\d+.\d+\\BLL\d+_IL\d+\\.*?\\TC\S+tcl',
        urlstring)
            copyFileCounts = 1
        except IOError as e:
            print "Can't open URL: {}".format(e.message)
```

it's a good practice to do the thing, and ask for forgiveness, so do whatever you want to do and then catch error if any.[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)